# NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '<collection element>' when validating list of string

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I am validating the content of a request using spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE

```
@RequestMapping(method = PATCH, value = "/{uniqueId}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserResource> setGlobalRoles(@PathVariable("uniqueId") String uniqueId,
        @Valid @RequestBody UserPatch patch) { ... }
```

The class looks like:

```
public class UserPatch {
  @Valid
  private List<@GlobalRoleExists String> globalRoles = new ArrayList<>();

  ...

  public List<String> getGlobalRoles() {
    return globalRoles;
  }

  public void setGlobalRoles(List<String> globalRoles) {
    this.globalRoles = globalRoles;
  }
```

The following error is thrown when one of the element of the list is not valid regarding the constraint.

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'globalRoles[1].<collection element>' of bean class [com.app.UserPatch]: Bean property 'globalRoles[1].<collection element>' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getRawFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:283) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.getRejectedValue(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:148) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:117) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:891) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:270) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

I notice that the path 'globalRoles[1].' is generated by hibernate (org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.path.NodeImpl), but I dont know if I am missing something or if it is just not possible to do that.

Comment: Can you put the entire class in order to see the getters/setters ?

Comment: I have updated my post to add the getters/setters I have declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue when upgrading from Spring Boot 1.4.x to 1.5.6.

The issue is documented at the [Spring issue tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15916) and was caused by a change in the string that's generated in Hibernate 5.3.x when a validation failure occurs.

Spring Framework 4.3.11 should include the fix, in the meantime you can explicitly specify a dependency on Hibernate version 5.2.5 (i.e. `compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.2.5.Final'`
 if you're using Gradle).

Comment: Thanks, I moved to spring framework 4.3.11 and it solved the problem.